# jQuery animation skipped when clicking quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zCg4t/)

If you click on the divs on the top quickly enough, you'll find that eventually two divs end up appearing. I've had this problem with jQuery before as well. I just ended up **disabling the buttons (or animation triggers)** in that case, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this.

Here is my jQuery code -

```
        $(function () {
            var _animDuration = 400;
            $("#tabLists a").click(function () {
                var attrHref = $(this).attr('href');
                // Get shown anchor and remove that class -
                $('.shownAnchor').removeClass('shownAnchor');
                $(this).addClass('shownAnchor');
                // first hide currently shown div,
                $('.shownDiv').fadeOut(_animDuration, function () {
                    debugger;
                    // then remove the shownDiv class, show the clicked div.
                    $(this).removeClass('shownDiv');
                    $('#' + attrHref).fadeIn(_animDuration, function () {
                        // then add that shownDiv class to the div currently being shown.
                        $(this).addClass('shownDiv');
                    })
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

I'm using callbacks everywhere. I would like a solution that would queue up the animation rather than, not allow me to click

Comment: I clicked and clicked and clicked but all that happened for me was the text fading in and out.

Answer (score 0):

try this code with a check var:

```
$(function(){
                var check = 1;
                var _animDuration = 400;
                $("#tabLists a").click(function(){
                    if(check == 1){
                        check = 0;
                        var attrHref = $(this).attr('href');                    
                        // Get shown anchor and remove that class -
                        $('.shownAnchor').removeClass('shownAnchor');
                        $(this).addClass('shownAnchor');
                        // first hide currently shown div,
                        $('.shownDiv').fadeOut(_animDuration, function(){
                            debugger;
                            // then remove the shownDiv class, show the clicked div.
                            $(this).removeClass('shownDiv');
                            $('#' + attrHref).fadeIn(_animDuration, function(){
                                // then add that shownDiv class to the div currently being shown.
                                $(this).addClass('shownDiv');   
                                check = 1;
                            })
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zCg4t/1/)

Comment: I would like an option that would queue up the animation rather than, not allow me to click